# Kindle footnote preview overflow

Tags: kindle, footnotes

I am creating an ebook. I'm making the epub in Sigil, and then converting it to mobi in Calibre. Not that it matters, but I'm working on Ubuntu.

I have endnotes set up as follows:

- In the chapters, I have [x] as both an anchor and a link where x is a number. Each chapter is in its own xhtml file.
- The endnotes are all collected in an xhtml file at the end. Each endnote starts with [x] which is also both an anchor and a link.
- Thus, if you click on a number in the chapter it is linked to the end note and vice versa.

More detail: Something like this:

- Reference in chapter: `<p id="ch01-01"><a href="../Text/Endnote.html#en01-01">[1]<\a><\p>`
- Reference in endnote: `<p id="en01-01"><a href="../Text/Ch01#ch01-01">[1]<\a><\p>`

The endnotes are structured like this:

> **Chapter 1 (a heading linked back to the chapter xhtml)**
>
> [1] endnote 1, linked back to the chapter 1 reference 1
>
> [2] endnote 2, linked back to the chapter 1 reference 2
>
> ...
>
> **Chapter 2**
>
> [1] endnote 1, linked back to chapter 2 reference 1.
>
> Etc

This all works well except for one thing.

When I convert it into a Kindle book, it very helpfully makes a pop-up preview of the endnote, with an option to go visit the end notes. This is the hoped for behavior.

However, when I click on the final endnote in a chapter, it does not accurately discern where the endnote ends. So the preview has the endnote and then runs over with more from the endnotes, such as the next chapter heading and sometimes even the first few endnotes from the next chapter.

How does the Kindle footnote previewer know that the footnote has ended? Is there a way to pass it a false signal? For example, it would be possible to put in an empty footnote with just the anchors and links. But I wondered if there was a cleaner or more correct way (and if that would even work, though intuitively it should).

Comment: Apparently, the Kindle heuristic to determine when and what to pop up is unknown and notoriously hard to game.